# Difficulty when configuring JUnit in Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, junit, junit4

i need help to install Junit in my computer, so I can create unit tests to run in JMeter.
The problem is that when I try to test if the JUnit installation is correct, it gives the following message:
"Error: Could not find or load main class org.junit.runner.JUnitCore"
Here are the configurations of the variables:
Environment variables

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03
JUNIT_HOME = C:\junit
in Path = %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JUNIT_HOME%\junit-4.10.jar
```

Tests in cmd:

```
C:\Users\luis.ribeiro>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03

C:\Users\luis.ribeiro>echo %JUNIT_HOME%
C:\junit

C:\Users\luis.ribeiro>java -version
java version "1.7.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode)

C:\Users\luis.ribeiro>java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore org.junit.tests.AllTests
Error: Could not find or load main class org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
```

Could someone help me with this problem please.
I will be very thank full,

With the best regards,
Luis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add junit to the CLASSPATH, not the PATH.

Example from the [FAQ](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#running_1):

```
set CLASSPATH=%JUNIT_HOME%\junit.jar;c:\myproject\classes;c:\myproject\lib\something.jar
```